# Passing data between two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

Let's say I'd like to pass data from Fragment A to Fragment B but it throws a nullpointerexception at Fragment B. I'd like to pass the data without use of activity. How do I resolve this?

In FragmentA.java

```
FragmentB ldf = new FragmentB ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("gender", genderSelected);
args.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
args.putString("contact", contactNo.getText().toString());
args.putString("age", age.getText().toString());
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,ldf).commit();
```

In FragmentB.java - in onCreateView() method

//Receive data from previous fragment - to be submitted in save

```
 String age = getArguments().getString("age");
 String gender = getArguments().getString("gender");
 String contact = getArguments().getString("contact");
 String name = getArguments().getString("name");
```

Comment: before that check your all argument have value?

Comment: Post the null pointer exception

Comment: could you post the signature of your onCreateView method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Fragment A is Perfect but in Fragment B you need to change as per following code.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String age = bundle.getString("age");
String gender = bundle.getString("gender");
String contact = bundle.getString("contact");
String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

Direct communication between fragment and fragment is not proper way.[Refers this link.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a static method on your class FragmentB

```
public static FragmentB newInstance(String gender, String name, String contact, String age) {

    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("gender", genderSelected);
    args.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
    args.putString("contact", contactNo.getText().toString());
    args.putString("age", age.getText().toString());
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}//newInstance
```

and

```
//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,FragmentB.newInstance(gender,name,contact,age)).commit();
```

finally get the datas in your onCreateView() as you did!